# Taking limit out of a bounded linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm reading a proof in text book and have a question about one step in there. Assume $\mu$ is a bounded linear operator, then naturally the author takes the limit out of a bounded linear operator: $$\mu\left(\lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{m} c_{n} x_{n}\right)=\lim _{m \rightarrow \infty} \mu\left(\sum_{n=1}^{m} c_{n} x_{n}\right)$$

Is that legit? Is bounded linear $\mu$ enough for the claim?

Comment: That depends on what sort of topological vector spaces are involved. It's legitimate if bounded linear operators are continuous. This is not the case for all topological vector spaces, but for normed spaces, a linear operator is bounded if and only if it is continuous. An unfortunate consequence of this fact is that many people say "bounded" when they mean "continuous", since they don't think of non-normable spaces.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I have added a line to my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, what you are asking is if $x_n \to x$, does $\mu(x_n) \to \mu(x)$?
This follows from $|\mu(x_n - x)| \le \|\mu\|\|x_n - x\|$. Since $\mu$ is a bounded linear operator $\|\mu\| < \infty$ and the proof is done.

I am assuming a normed linear space.